# Layout of ComboBox items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have ComboBox item style as follows (simplified):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" />
            <Path Grid.Column="1" Style={StaticResource StarStyle}/>
</Grid>
```

The result is as expected. An item in my list looks as follows:

[alt text http://robbertdam.nl/share/p1.png](http://robbertdam.nl/share/p1.png)

Howver, when I select that item. It looks like this:

[alt text http://robbertdam.nl/share/p2.png](http://robbertdam.nl/share/p2.png)

I want to have the stars right aligned. What am I missing?

Comment: I too enjoy it when the stars align right. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I've defined this Style

```
        <Style x:Key="ComboItemsStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
```

Assigning this style to my ComboBox solves it:

```
        <Style x:Key="ComboStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
```

Comment: Ah of course - the "stretch" thing is a common problem with ComboBoxes and ListBoxes. I wish MS had made it the default, because *everybody* makes the same mistake (myself included).

Answer (score 1):

Does the "Path" object have an "Align" property? That is, can you force it to align right with this XAML?

```
<Path Grid.Column="1" Align="Right" Style={StaticResource StarStyle}/>
```

**Edit**

No, it doesn't. In that case, I'd suggest embedding the path into a container that can align it. Perhaps:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <Path DockPanel.Dock="Right" Style={StaticResource StarStyle}/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I already found the solution. See my answer.